# Backup to Google Drive - Disabled by your admin. Why does my device show is? It's preventing me from restoring my backed up apps.

Tags: backup, google-drive

[image][image]

I'm trying to restore my apps that are backed up to Drive. I  keep getting this (screenshot) and cannot change so I can restore my apps. I even did a factory reset and was not offered the option to restore my apps. I don't have any idea what was done to make it return this now about the admin. It's my personal phone and nobody else uses it. I don't have a school or business account either which is where the help tells you to go and change admin.

Any help please there to resolve this. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thx much. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Posted an answer. It seems to be false alarm. As you can see from others on the thread, they are able to backup. You can try backing up. And share your experience as a comment to help future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

From [Google Product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/FLCIN88EdeM;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/category%243Aandroid%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) , this has been widely reported by Nougat users and is a **false alarm**

Reply from Google help yesterday (08 Aug)

> We just received a feedback from the Android team. The error that you are encountering is actually being **displayed by accident** for some Android Nougat users. It has no effect on your data being backed up or not. The status of backup being on or off is correctly captured in the first 'Backup & Reset' screen, and can be controlled by the user. For now, you can **safely ignore** the error message until a fix is rolled out by the Android team which should be around September 21, 2017.

(Emphasis Supplied)

Other users have reported that they have been able to restore despite the warning

Comment: False alarm or no, I believe this is a bug.  I've looked at a lot of forums and lots of people are chiming in on this issue.  I checked my Google Drive / Backups section (where these backups should get stored) and there hasn't been an update from this phone yet.  I've used my work / personal accounts as well, same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Gave an answer but it says the answer already exists yet answers said it's a false alarm. Problem is it's not false for every user as some show there are no backups and someone else reset their device but couldn't restore because it said there are no backups. It is a false alarm for some but not all. So users need to double check that a backup actually exists.

Comment: I've also checked the Google Drive / Backups, not a false alarm, no backups geting created.  How can it be a false alarm if the entire Google Accounts section doesn't show which apps you can backup?